# SQLALCHEMY initiate model class constructor (__init__) after query

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I Have a simple SQLALCHEMY Model like:

```
class User(db.Model):
     """ User Model for storing user related details """
     __tablename__ = "users"

     UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
     Email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
     UserName = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
     Password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
     #bla....

     def __init__(self, email, username, password):
          # private
         self.__private = 'testing'
         # bla...

     def test(self):
         print self.__private

    # bla....
```

and in my app I do a simple query:

```
user = User.query.filter((User.Email == req_email) | (User.UserName == req_username)).first()
```

problem: when i call

```
user.test()
```

it throws me error:

> 'User' object has no attribute '_User__private'

, because my private variable never been initialize in **init** function.

question: so, how to initiate class model after query called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`load`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load) event:

```
@event.listens_for(User, "load")
def set_private_after_load(target, context):
    target.__private = "testing"
```

Comment: Isn't there also the [`@orm.reconstructor`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html) shorthand/helper for that? Not that it'd differ from explicitly using the load event.